# Python word cloud centralization

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am using "WordCloud" library in python. I've tried to generate some word clouds but got a problem. How can I put the longest words in center of the cloud? There is no any point in documentation about it.

Comment: You can pass it word frequencies, and then set the frequency of the longest word artificially higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code snippet.

We first need to compute the absolute frequencies. To do that, we create a dict containing each word as a key, and its length as a value. We can then use wordcloud's function `generate_from_frequencies` in order to generate the wordcloud.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multidict
from wordcloud import WordCloud

def getFrequencyDictForText(word_list):
    fullTermsDict = multidict.MultiDict()

    # making dict for counting frequencies
    for text in word_list:
        fullTermsDict.add(text.lower(), len(text))

    return fullTermsDict

word_list = "Birds are a group of warm-blooded vertebrates constituting the class Aves characterised by feathers toothless beaked jaws the laying of hard-shelled eggs a high metabolic rate".split(" ")
    
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white")
wc.generate_from_frequencies(getFrequencyDictForText(word_list))

plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting output:
[image]

Comment: If I have some words sorted by frequency - which is the way to put most common of them in centre?